# Using GridSearchCV and a Random Forest Regressor with the same parameters gives different results

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

As the huge title says I'm trying to use GridSearchCV to find the best parameters for a Random Forest Regressor and I'm measuring my results with mse.

```
Inputs_Treino = dataset.iloc[:253,1:4].values
Outputs_Treino = dataset.iloc[:253,-1].values
Inputs_Teste = dataset.iloc[254:,1:4].values
Outputs_Teste = dataset.iloc[254:,-1].values

estimator = RandomForestRegressor()
para_grids = {
            "n_estimators" : [10,50,100],
            "max_features" : ["auto", "log2", "sqrt"],
            "bootstrap"    : [True, False]
        }


grid = GridSearchCV(estimator, para_grids, scoring = 'mean_squared_error')
grid.fit(Inputs_Treino, Outputs_Treino)
forest = grid.best_estimator_

reg_prediction=forest.predict(Inputs_Teste)

print (grid.best_score_, grid.best_params_)

mse = mean_absolute_error(Outputs_Teste, reg_prediction)
```

This is the gist of the code (nothing too complex I know, just getting started with it all)

When I print the result of grid.best_estimator_ I get this

```
RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           n_estimators=50, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
           verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

The problem is if I try to create a regressor with these parameters (without using grid search at all) and train it the same way I get a waaaay bigger MSE on the testing set (5.483837301587303 vs 43.801520165079467)

```
Inputs_Treino = dataset.iloc[:253,1:4].values
Outputs_Treino = dataset.iloc[:253,-1].values
Inputs_Teste = dataset.iloc[254:,1:4].values
Outputs_Teste = dataset.iloc[254:,-1].values

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           n_estimators=50, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
           verbose=0, warm_start=False)

regressor.fit(Inputs_Treino,Outputs_Treino)

#fazer as predictions
Teste_Prediction = regressor.predict(Inputs_Teste);

mse = mean_squared_error(Outputs_Teste, Teste_Prediction);
```

Does this have to do with the cross validation GridSearchCV performs ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried fixing a random_state? For instance:estimator = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0). This will help you achieve reproducibility of the algorithm no matter it is run under grid search or stand-alone.

Comment: @LucaMassaron yes, i tried it after this post. 

para_grids = {
            "n_estimators" : [10,50,100],
            "max_features" : ["auto", "log2", "sqrt"],
            "bootstrap"    : [True, False],
            "random_state"  : [0]
        } and I get the about the same difference in mse

Comment: Print the result of `grid.best_estimator_` after you have set the `random_state`. Do you include that when you use the `regressor` without grid-search?

Comment: First code, row 'mse = mean_absolute_error(Outputs_Teste, reg_prediction)' - it is not an error?

Comment: @avchauzov holy shit thank you, I don't know how I managed to miss that for so long.